# Azure AKS : Unable to access private cluster , getting error dial tcp: lookup .....privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io on 208.67.222.222:53: no such host

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

I've created a k8s cluster on `azure aks` using terraform `azurerm`, with the argument `private_cluster_enabled` set to true, to make my cluster full private.

The cluster resides in vnet on `10.49.0.0/16` and the subnet `10.49.0.0/24`. There a private link  to the vnet with A record :

```
pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io  --> 10.49.0.4
```

But the cluster is not reachable till I make the cluster public by setting the `private_cluster_enabled` argument to false.

The below ouput shows that the problem is at DNS resolution level.

aks resources are trying to lookup the cluster dns private link but fail, and I can see the lookup is made on public address. I don't why.

I've read all azure documentation but I don't know what to do else to bring my cluster up and running in private mode.

Here is an error output from  `terraform plan` when the state refresh tries to access the cluster. You can see we have a different `public IP` for resolution attempt.

Why the dns lookup uses public IPs?

```
ev-vdc1-aks-appgw/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/bf3c9ab5-c09d-602b-13ec-31b25be7273f]
module.k8s_cluster.module.appgw.azurerm_role_assignment.agic-rg[0]: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/1c172835-4f36-47f0-a300-f04192e27d65/resourceGroups/VDC1-LUGGIN-RG-DEV-VDC1/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/b7382e80-162b-719f-305b-db6c9b625806]

Error: Get "https://pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/standard-hdd-delete": dial tcp: lookup pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bcdb4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io on 208.67.222.222:53: no such host



Error: Get "https://pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/namespaces/system-cert-manager": dial tcp: lookup pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4
de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io on 208.67.222.222:53: no such host



Error: Get "https://pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/namespaces/system-agic": dial tcp: lookup pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io on 208.67.222.222:53: no such host


 Error: Get "https://pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/storageclasses/standard-hdd-retain": dial tcp: lookup pda-aks-luggin-euw-dev-vdc1-aks-3bc4db4c.7ac6ebd0-8d3f-4de0-ab05-ab79e0b0d984.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io on 208.67.222.222:53: no such host
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access the cluster from?  Remember, since it's private, you can only access it from a bastion host/VM in the same VNET (or peered VNET).

Comment: @RickRainey do you mean where I'm running my `terraform plan`? To build a private cluster do I need to be in the same vnet as the the cluster I'm provisioning?

Comment: No, you don't.  It sounded like your deployment was fine and then you were not able to connect to it.

Comment: Yes @RickRainey, you are right, there was the issue, I didn't check inside the terraform module I used, to see how it's designed.